# Unable to create oracle_fdw extension on Postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle12c, foreign-data-wrapper, oracle-fdw

I am following the instructions [here](http://blog.dbi-services.com/connecting-your-postgresql-instance-to-an-oracle-database/) to install Oracle foreign data wrapper, [oracle_fdw](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw), on a PostgreSQL server.

**Oracle version:** Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production, running on Red Hat Linux 7.2

**PostgreSQL version:** PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 4.7.2-5) 4.7.2, 64-bit, running on Debian 7 (wheezy).

I was able to install sqlplus and connect from PostgreSQL server to Oracle server using sqlplus successfully, so connectivity is not a problem.

But when I try to create the extension, I get the following error:

```
postgres=# create extension oracle_fdw;
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
```

Then I took clues from https://github.com/dalibo/pg_qualstats/issues/1 and added oracle_fdw to shared_preload_libraries in postgresql.conf like this:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'oracle_fdw'
```

but now I can't restart Postgres:

```
# service postgresql restart
[....] Restarting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server: main[....] The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: t=2016-09-15 11:05:42 PDT d= h= p=23300 a=FATAL: XX000: invalid cache ID[FAILt=2016-09-15 11:05:42 PDT d= h= p=23300 a=LOCATION: SearchSysCacheList, syscache.c:1219 ... failed!
 failed!
```

Looking into /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log I only see these two lines:

```
t=2016-09-15 11:05:42 PDT d= h= p=23300 a=FATAL:  XX000: invalid cache ID: 41
t=2016-09-15 11:05:42 PDT d= h= p=23300 a=LOCATION:  SearchSysCacheList, syscache.c:1219
```

Removing oracle_fdw from shared_preload_libraries allows postgres to be restarted, so this is the one causing restart to fail. So I removed oracle_fdw from shared_preload_libraries and kept it just like this in postgresql.conf:

```
shared_preload_libraries = ''
```

Then I was able to restart Postgres.

---

Here are the exact steps done:

#### OS version for PostgreSQL server

```
# cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
root@app-4:/# cat /etc/debian_version
7.8
root@app-4:/# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)
Release:    7.8
Codename:   wheezy
```

#### Installation of Oracle Instant Client

Installed using the instructions given here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client

I downloaded the following rpm files from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html:

- oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient-devel-10.2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm
- oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-10.2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm

and installed them on the PostgreSQL server using the following commands:

```
# apt-get install alien
# alien -i oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm
# alien -i oracle-instantclient-devel-10.2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm
# alien -i oracle-instantclient-sqlplus-10.2.0.3-1.x86_64.rpm
```

Confirming the installations:

```
# dpkg --list | grep -i oracle
ii  oracle-instantclient-basic         10.2.0.3-2                    amd64        Instant Client for Oracle Database 11g
ii  oracle-instantclient-devel         10.2.0.3-2                    amd64        Development headers for Instant Client.
ii  oracle-instantclient-sqlplus       10.2.0.3-2                    amd64        SQL*Plus for Instant Client.
```

#### Connecting to Oracle server using sqlplus

```
# su - postgres
postgres@app-4:~$ sqlplus <ORACLE_USER>/<ORACLE_PASS>@//<ORACLE_HOST>:<ORACLE_PORT>/<SID>

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Fri Sep 16 09:55:02 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select count(*) from <TEST_TABLE>;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    937530

SQL>
```

So this works fine.

#### Installing oracle_fdw

Downloaded oracle_fdw version 1.4.0 i.e. file oracle_fdw-1.4.0.zip from 
http://pgxn.org/dist/oracle_fdw/

Then unzipped it and installed it like this:

```
root@app-4:/home/arun/oracle_fdw-1.4.0# ls
CHANGELOG  LICENSE   META.json             oracle_fdw--1.1.sql  oracle_fdw.control  oracle_fdw.o   oracle_gis.c  oracle_utils.c  README.oracle_fdw  TODO
expected   Makefile  oracle_fdw--1.0--1.1.sql  oracle_fdw.c     oracle_fdw.h    oracle_fdw.so  oracle_gis.o  oracle_utils.o  sql
root@app-4:/home/arun/oracle_fdw-1.4.0# make
...
root@app-4:/home/arun/oracle_fdw-1.4.0# make install
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension'
/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.4/extension'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 755  oracle_fdw.so '/usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/lib/oracle_fdw.so'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 oracle_fdw.control '/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 oracle_fdw--1.1.sql oracle_fdw--1.0--1.1.sql '/usr/share/postgresql/9.4/extension/'
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 README.oracle_fdw '/usr/share/doc/postgresql-doc-9.4/extension/'
```

#### Creating extension in Postgres

```
root@app-4:/# su - postgres
postgres@app-4:~$ psql
psql (9.4.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create extension oracle_fdw;
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Failed.
!> \q
```

---

#### Stack Trace

I installed the GNU debugger (gdb) as recommended by Laurenz Albe in his answer and got the following stack trace (without the debugging symbols for now):

```
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ff657dfcc99 in DirectFunctionCall1Coll ()
#2  0x00007ff657de19a9 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ff657de3037 in SearchCatCacheList ()
#4  0x00007ff4c5fcce7d in _PG_init () at oracle_fdw.c:648
#5  0x00007ff657dfb717 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007ff657dfc051 in load_external_function ()
#7  0x00007ff657b6b486 in fmgr_c_validator ()
#8  0x00007ff657dfdeba in OidFunctionCall1Coll ()
#9  0x00007ff657b6aedc in ProcedureCreate ()
#10 0x00007ff657bcf645 in CreateFunction ()
#11 0x00007ff657d14e73 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007ff657d140c7 in standard_ProcessUtility ()
#13 0x00007ff657bc89ed in ?? ()
#14 0x00007ff657bc98de in CreateExtension ()
#15 0x00007ff657d154c1 in ?? ()
#16 0x00007ff657d140c7 in standard_ProcessUtility ()
#17 0x00007ff657d11243 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007ff657d11e96 in ?? ()
#19 0x00007ff657d12b3d in PortalRun ()
#20 0x00007ff657d0fb1a in PostgresMain ()
#21 0x00007ff657acbdad in ?? ()
#22 0x00007ff657caf351 in PostmasterMain ()
#23 0x00007ff657acccba in main ()
Continuing.

Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.
```

---

**UPDATE**: I was able to install the extension on Postgres 9.4.9 running on debian 8 (8.6, jessie). I used Oracle instant client version 12.1.0.2.0-1 and oracle_fdw version 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really open a Github issue for that, that's the correct place to report an error.

The answer to the following questions will help:

- Which version of `oracle_fdw` are you using?
- What are the exact steps you used to build it? Did you build it on the system where you are running it?
- How does the [stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Getting_a_stack_trace_of_a_running_PostgreSQL_backend_on_Linux/BSD) of the crash look (with debugging symbols)?

Two general remarks:

- You should follow the [README](https://raw.github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/ORACLE_FDW_1_5_0/README.oracle_fdw) for building `oracle_fdw` and no other web site.
- Adding it to `shared_preload_libraries` is plain wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the double posting here and in the Postgres general mailing group. Wasn't sure from where I would be getting answers sooner, so I double posted. Will update my question with the details you ask for.

Comment: I added the exact steps I did. Pls let me know if you see anything wrong there. I will work on getting the stack trace next.

Comment: I am at a loss on how to install debug symbols. The stack trace has lot of entries with `??` and is useless as is.

Comment: If you installed PostgreSQL from source, you'll have to `./configure --enable-debug`. Otherwise, there is a section *Installing External symbols* in the PostgreSQL Wiki page I referenced in my answer. To build `oracle_fdw` with debugging symbols, try `CC='gcc -g' make`.

Comment: You can start by showing the stack trace without debugging symbols. Sometimes that information is enough.

Comment: Thx, Laurenz. I added the stack trace (without debugging symbols).

Comment: That's enough to determine that the crash occurs [here](https://github.com/laurenz/oracle_fdw/blob/master/oracle_fdw.c#L648). To say more, debugging symbols for PostgreSQL would be required. Does this happen always? I couldn't find a bug fixed since PostgreSQL 9.4.4 that might cause a crash like this, but it would be interesting if this also happens with 9.4.9.

Comment: Sorry this took a while to work on, but good news finally :). I could install the extension successfully on Postgres 9.4.9 on debian 8.6 (jessie). Thanks so much for being patient on this and trying to help me debug.

Answer (score 1):

why do you use an oracle 10.2.0.3 instant against an Oracle 12.1.0.2 database? I'd recommend to use the latest version of instant client.

"SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Fri Sep 16 09:55:02 2016"

When you use a debian based system do not use the instant client rpms and convert them to a deb package, use the zip versions and set your environment accordingly.

I'll see if I find some time to test your setup

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: Check here for an example on Debian 8: http://blog.dbi-services.com/connecting-your-postgresql-instance-to-an-oracle-database-debian-version/

Comment: Thx. Everything works fine once I upgraded to Postgres 9.4.9.